# going to fetch a value from xml response when going to parse but i am fail to get value

Tags: iphone, xcode, xml-parsing, objective-c-2.0

Below code is the response from the server:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><SendCardDetailsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><SendCardDetailsResult><ROOT xmlns=""><DocumentElement><res-auth><auth-data count='1' ><**attribute name='OTP1'** length='6' type='N' label='OTP' prompt='Please enter OTP as send to your mobile.'/></auth-data></res-auth></DocumentElement></ROOT></SendCardDetailsResult></SendCardDetailsResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

I have to fetch attribute name which is 'OTP1'
how can I get value of attribute name 
any help will be appreciable

Comment: it is not XML i guess. Check below

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<shiporder orderid="889923"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="shiporder.xsd">
  <orderperson>John Smith</orderperson>
  <shipto>
    <name>Ola Nordmann</name>
    <address>Langgt 23</address>
    <city>4000 Stavanger</city>
    <country>Norway</country>
  </shipto>
  <item>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <note>Special Edition</note>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>10.90</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>9.90</price>

Comment: by using nsxmlparser class and parsing delegate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use smth like this:

```
-(NSString*) getAttribute{
    NSString *attribute = @"";
    NSString *xmlString = @"";//put the XML in this NSString
    int endOfSrc = [xmlString rangeOfString:@"\"><attribute name='"].location+[xmlString rangeOfString:@"\"><attribute name='"].length;
    int borderPos = [xmlString rangeOfString:@"' length='"].location;
    if(borderPos != NSNotFound){
        NSRange range;
        range.location = endOfSrc;
        range.length = borderPos - endOfSrc;
        attribute = [xmlString substringWithRange:range];
        return attribute;
    }
    return @" ";
}
```

Nothing hard here, if some questions about the code appear, just see the documentation for the functions i've used here.
maybe there are more efficient ways, dunno. It works like a charm for me.

Comment: @dumoko..thanx for your reply i m using this code but i m confuse wiht the rangeOfString ,is i have to give the value of range ? will you explain me how to use this method....

Comment: rangeofString gives you a NSRange value with 2 fields: the index where \"><attribute name=' starts(location) and its length, so endOfSrc will have the index where the \"><attribute name=' ends and the attribute starts. borderPos just finds where the attribute will end. So, we know the index where the attribute begins, and where it ends. So we just have to substring between these 2 indexes. And btw, if my answer helped you, could u pls check it as "Accepted"?